# TIme complexity for a specific loop

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

What is the time complexity and tilde for the loop below?

```
for (int i = N/2; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < N; j++) {
        doSomething(i, j);
    }
}
```

I think that it runs `N/2 + (N/2 + 1) + (N/2 + 2) + ... + (N-1)` times, but how do I get it's time complexity and tilde?

For example - if `N = 100`, the loop will run `50 + 51 + 52 + 53 + ... + 99` times.

Comment: Hint: 50+99 = 51+98 = 52+97 ...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming  **doSomething(i, j);** is not iterating all the elements between i and j; if this is the case, the complexity of this algorithm is O(N^2).

The outer loop **for (int i = N/2; i < N; i++) {** will execute O(N) times, cause N/2 is actually constant value.

The inner loop in worst case will execute N times (or N - i times) too, this will also merge with previous O(N).

Therefore, overall time complexity will be O(N^2) in worst case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop is executed:

> N/2-1 times for i = N/2,
>
> N/2-2 times for i = N/2+1
>
> ....
>
> 1 time for i = N-2

therefore the total time for the inner loop is :

> (N/2-1) + (N/2-2) + .... (N/2-k) where k = N/2 - 1
>
> = N/2*k - (1 + 2 + ... + k)
>
> = N/2*(N/2-1) - (N/2-1)(N/2)/2
>
> = N/2(N/2 - 1 - N/4 + 1/2)
>
> = N/2(N/4 - 1/2)
>
> = N^2/8 - N/4

Hence the order of growth of the code is of `N^2`

If you consider tilde notation which is defined as :

"*`∼g(n)` to represent any quantity that, when divided by `f(n)`, approaches 1 as n grows*" from [here](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/41analysis/), you can see that `~g(n)` = `~N^2/8` because as `N` grows `(N^2/8)/(N^2/8-N/4)` approaches 1.